# server dependency diagram for enterprise systems. Not code

Tags: dependencies, system, enterprise

I am looking for a good (possibly opensource/free) tool which allows me to record data about our servers (over 50) and provides a method to identify dependencies. So for example Server 1 being up and fully functional may depend on servers 5 and 6 being up. I usually depict this in a diagram with the server 1 in a box and "5,6" written beneath it. From this you can not only see its dependencies, but also what server it is, OS, Version etc, DB/ APP.

This will be very useful in a backup/recovery scenario, also allows us to keep details on each server.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like something like this too. Ideally some simple text notation to record it all them options to spit out diagrams at different levels of detail etc. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment diagram in UML with dependencies links.

Comment: This draws a dependency line between each device. This diagram will be far too complicated with lines going everywhere. Which is why I asked if numbers can represent dependencies. I am using "Enterprise Architect"